# onPostExecute is not called

Tags: java, android, android-studio, android-asynctask

So I am having issues with my `AsyncTask`. I need `postExecute` to display an alert dialog if a certain error throwable is caught in `doInBackground`. The problem is that `postExecute` is never called. I have tried adding `@Override` but Android Studio says that it isn't overriding a method in its super class. I have also tried changing the return type. I looked around this site and couldn't find an answer. Thanks in advance.

AsyncTask Class

```
public class AsyncTaskActivity extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    String exception;

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
    }


    protected void onPostExecute() {
        if (exception.contains("java.net.UnknownHostException")) {
            MainActivity.showDialog();
            Log.i("Error Message", "ERROR MESSAGE SHOWN");
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        try {
            Log.i("AsyncTask", "Loading...");
            // Make a URL to the web page. This takes the string representation of the URL
            // and changes it into a URL object
            URL url = new URL("http://api.wunderground.com/api/0c0fcc3bf62ab910/conditions/q/IN/Fort_Wayne.json");

            // Get the input stream through URL Connection
            URLConnection con = url.openConnection();
            InputStream is = con.getInputStream();

            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(is));

            String line;
            // read each line and write to text file
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                Log.i("AsyncTask", line);
                TextEditor.file = new File(MainActivity.path, "siteInfo.txt");
                TextEditor.writeString(line);
            }
            TextEditor.saveAndClose();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            exception = e.toString();
        }

        Log.i("AsyncTask", "DONE");
        return null;
    }
}
```

showDialog method

```
public static void showDialog() {
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.context);
    builder.setView(R.layout.dialog_layout);
    builder.setPositiveButton(
            R.string.dialog_close,
            new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    System.exit(1);
                }
            });

    builder.show();
}
```

Comment: Look at the method signature for onPostExecute() from the docs, you're missing a parameter.

Comment: where is @Override in onPostExecute ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

look like you're missing something

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
    if (exception.contains("java.net.UnknownHostException")) {
        MainActivity.showDialog();
        Log.i("Error Message", "ERROR MESSAGE SHOWN");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Can you explain why `Void result` works? I thought the parameter was of the type result?

Comment: Quote from another answer of another question: OnPostExecute() takes an argument (the object you return from doInBackground()). Change it to protected void onPostExecute(Void v). If you don't provide the argument, the method signatures do not match and the override annotation starts to complain that there is no function to override with this signature.

Answer (score 0):

First please refer this documentation. you have missed parameters on onPostExecute().

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

What you would have to do is,

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Params) {
        // your logics 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
    if (exception.contains("java.net.UnknownHostException")) {
        MainActivity.showDialog();
        Log.i("Error Message", "ERROR MESSAGE SHOWN");
    }
}
```

Please note that you need to initialize exception, otherwise it may cause a NullPointerException